# how to inhibit R garbage collection when passing objects to C/C++?

Tags: c++, r

Having some trouble with R's garbage collection, when passing objects to C++.

We have the following scenario:

1. we create an anonymous function in R, and pass it to C++ code (via `.Call()`)
2. the C++ code stores the R function object for later use (as a `SEXP` type) and returns
3. later on, some other C++ code invokes said R function object using `R_tryEval()`

Between steps 2 and 3, the R function object appears to get garbage-collected by R. This leads to a crash because `R_tryEval()` tries to execute something that no longer represents a valid R function object.  That's fair, as we haven't done anything to tell R that the function object is still in use...

With that in mind:

- is there a way, from the C++ code, to mark the R function object as being in-use (such that it doesn't get gc'd)?
- or is there a safe way to duplicate the R function object, within the C++ code, and manually dispose of it after we invoke `R_tryEval()`?

(As far as I understand, the `PROTECT()`/`UNPROTECT()` macros are not an option here because those are supposed to balance out within the same scope.  As in, we can't call `PROTECT()` when the function is first passed to C++ and then later call `UNPROTECT()` after it has been executed.)

Comment: How are you 'storing' the object?  I'd think (without actually thinking) you can employ an external pointer.  If not, you might be able to simply keep it alive in R somewhere and use findVar to recall it when needed.

Comment: @Jeff -- thanks.  What you've described is very close to the workaround we devised: adding the function objects to a list, on the R side, before passing them to C++.  (We're happy to keep doing this, by the way... just wanted to make sure there's no "official" function we're supposed to call to flag the object as do-not-gc.)

Comment: As far as hacks go, this may take the cake. See Martin's answer for a proper solution even if you don't use Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
/* preserve objects across GCs */
void R_PreserveObject(SEXP);
void R_ReleaseObject(SEXP);
```

in the R_internals.h header.

Comment: ... and if you used Rcpp this would be applied automagically to your objects.